# Cannot connect or ping Firewall/Gateway but internet is fine

Tags: firewall, gateway

I cannot ping my Gateway or connect to it via browser. My internet however works fine, how is this possible? Using Advanced IP Scanner i can also find the IP adress of my Gateway as active. I tried to connect through a couple of different computers with the same result. The Gateway is also an DHCP server.

What can i do to connect to the Gateway (its a firewall)

Hardware is a UTT Hiper 3300. Its a Chinese Brand.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. The firewall doesn't have a web interface or the web interface is on a different port than the one you're trying to connect to. 2. The firewall doesn't respond to ICMP Echo Requests (ping). 3. The firewall does respond to the ARP scan initiated by Advanced IP Scanner, which it should, otherwise you wouldn't have access to the internet.

Comment: Neither ping or gui access are needed for the router to provide access to the internet.  Are you saying you were able to access the gui previously?

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your gateway does not respond to ICMP Echo Requests, otherwise known as ping's. It's actually quite common for this to be the case, and must be in this situation.

I've found these documents which reference a Web UI, as well as other access methods.

[Translated specifications sheet](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.utt.com.cn/download/documents/HiPER%25203300VF.pdf&prev=/search%3Fq%3DUTT%2BHiper%2B3300%26safe%3Doff)

[Untranslated user guide](http://www.utt.com.cn/download/manual/HiPER%20ReOS%205.0%B8%DF%BC%B6%C5%E4%D6%C3%CA%D6%B2%E1.pdf)

If you cannot connect to the gateway on the internal LAN on either port 80, port 443, or port 8080 (http://[gateway-ip] or https://[gateway-ip] or http://[gateway-ip]:8080 or https://[gateway-ip]:8080) then it is most likely in a bridged mode. You might try resetting the gateway and see if you are able to access it then. Bear in mind though, any configuration will be lost after a full reset. An alternative would be to run a port scan and see what ports are open - if any - and this should help in finding the access ports.

If the router was in a bridged mode, however, you would not see a gateway address for the device or be receiving DHCP from this device, but it is possible you could be seeing this information coming from an upstream device - such as an ISP's gateway which could be handing out private IP addresses - again, very uncommon, but possible.

Of course, all of these things would be dependent upon your current LAN setup and your ISP's routing configuration. Unfortunately, the only way of truly knowing how to access and configure your gateway/firewall would be to have readable documentation on the device. The previous spec's sheet and the untranslated user guide were the only documentation I could find, unfortunately.